# I have this HTML and need help writing an XpathQueryString

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I am trying to write an XPath to pull the value 4.4690 from the tag below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id=currency_converter_result>10 BRL = <span class=bld>4.4690 USD</span>
   <input type=submit value="Convert">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the span's text and use [`substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) to extract the part of a text before the `USD`:

```
substring-before(//div[@id="currency_converter_result"]/span[@class="bld"], " USD")
```

Comment: You can strip out the `/text()` step as the element value will be automatically cast to an atomic value

Comment: @RonBledsoe nope, you haven't accepted it yet. Also, go through your past questions and see if any of the answers deserve to be accepted. Thank you.